# Angular2 using Webpack2 result in big size of bundle files

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-2

I'm playing with build trying to assemble optimal one to understand what is what in this Angular2, Webpack2, ZoneJs, SystemJs, TypeScript soup.

I'm concern with size of bundled files. Is that normal for development, non minimized and uglified files? What should be the target size for production versions of dependencies?

Please follow red arrows on pic below for file sizes. All relevant files are shown.

[image]

Comment: The file size, resulted from a dev build, looks OK to me, what was the size before you migrate to Webpack 2?

Comment: Looks good to me. Just try doing a Prod build with & without Webpack -p option to get a clear understanding on build size...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it is OK for Webpack, production build size starts from ~800KB.